# How to change field name to default NULL

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

I want to change my field name to default Null but i am unable to solve this issue Here i am trying to change my deleteAt field to defaut Null but its giving me the error

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an 
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
>   'deletedAt timestamp default NULL' at
>   line 1

Here is my code

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE insurance CHANGE COLUMN deleted_at deletedAt timestamp default NULL');
```

I want to set default NULL but i am unable to solve this and i am confused about this issue. your help need here

Comment: May we ask why you are trying to run table maintenance commands from your app layer?  Why not run this directly on MySQL?

Comment: deletedat isn't valid syntax - error is self-explanatory

Comment: changing delete_at to deletedAt is requirement i can changed it but i am unable to change default value to NULL that is my issue i am facing

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE insurance CHANGE COLUMN deleted_at deletedAt timestamp default NULL
```

Is incorrect.
Use this please.

```
ALTER TABLE insurance MODIFY COLUMN deleted_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

The word deletedAt isn't a valid syntax. There is an error in your query.

Comment: This is the requirement i can successfully change delete_at to deletedAt but now i want to change default value to Null this is my problem

Comment: @syed1234 I have updated the code. in the end, telling NULL is stating that null value is allowed and afterwards DEFAULT NULL states that the default value will be null when nothing is given. Please try it.

Comment: still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE `insurance` CHANGE COLUMN `deleted_at` 
`deleted_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```